# Prononciation du singulier et du pluriel : « ce » et « ces »

Tags: prononciation, pluriel, démonstratifs, déterminants

Y a-t-il une différence entre la prononciation de **ce beau tabouret** et **ces beaux tabourets** ?

Comment est-ce possible de distinguer, en écoutant, si on parle au singulier ou au pluriel ? Habituellement, on peut distinguer le singulier et le pluriel avec la prononciation… Par exemple: **le petit tabouret** et **les petits tabourets** (**le** et **les** ont différentes prononciations).

Est-ce la même chose avec **ce** et **ces** ?

---

Is there any difference between the pronunciation of **ce beau tabouret** and **ces beaux tabourets**?

How is it possible, listening to someone, to understand if he/she refers to singular or plural? Usually I think it's possible to distinguish is, as they're pronounced in a different way. For example: **le petit tabouret** and **les petits tabourets** (**le** and **les** are pronounced in a different way).

Is it the same with **ce** and **ces**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference in pronunciation between 'ce' and 'ces' is the same as 'le' and 'les'.